# How can I use conditional expression in html to control the display?

Tags: html, laravel

I want to put the following conditional expression in html to control the display in blade in laravel, but I can't get to "$response.ResultCode". How can I do this?

```
@if ($response.ResultCode == "0000")
<HTML content>
@endif
```

In js, I am able to access as follows.

```
if(@json($response).ResultCode ! = "0000") {
   hoge;     
}
```

Comment: Did you try with `@if (@json($response).ResultCode == "0000")` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried it but was said there isn't function json.

Comment: You can access it as `$response->ResultCode` if expression is an object, `$response['ResultCode']` if it is an array.

Comment: @Semih SAHIN Thank you! I passed with that! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use access operator for this

```php
$response->ResultCode
```